# How to ignore numbers being selected from a List<string>?

Tags: c#

I have a list of items such as

A1
A2
A3
B1
C1
F1
1A
2A

and I use the following code to get a list of distinct strings representing the first letter of each group:

```
var result = groups.Select(xx => xx.Name.Substring(0, 1)).Distinct().ToList();
```

so this returns a list like follows:

A
B
C
F
1
2

This is all good, except for the numbers... Is there an easy way for me to modify the code to return only letters, so if it's a number it won't be added to the `results` group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var result = groups.Select(x => x.Name[0])
                   .Where(c => char.IsLetter(c))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

Note that the above query will generate a `List<char>`. If you want a `List<string>` instead then you'll need to do something like this:

```
var result = groups.Select(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1))
                   .Where(s => char.IsLetter(s[0]))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a function: `bool IsDigit(char c)`

```
 var result = groups.Select(x=>x.Name.Substring(0, 1)).Where(x => !IsDigit(c)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or

Use LukeH's answer :D